# Replace Git history with one commit

Tags: git, rebase

I have following repository:

```
* d9da0f2 (HEAD, master) Fifth
| * bf3b476 (branch1) branch1 first
|/  
* 13f93d5 Fourth
* 94f2fa1 Third
* 5333eb2 Second
* be69a71 First
```

All I am trying to do is doing something to it to get the following structure:

```
* d9da0f2 (HEAD, master) Fifth
| * bf3b476 (branch1) branch1 first
|/  
* ?13f93d5? Reworded commit, with all the other commmits squashed/fixuped into it
```

I tried following:

```
git checkout 13f93d5
git rebase -i --root

reword be69a71 First
fixup 5333eb2 Second
fixup 94f2fa1 Third
fixup 13f93d5 Fourth
```

but ended up with:

```
* commit a6a091c9bc495b9de5ca51dee5d0032454e669db (HEAD)
  Author: frigo <frigo@dev>
  Date:   Fri Nov 7 20:18:55 2014 +0100

      First reworded

* commit d9da0f2f273b91913ac241f3b6b034ef7babf1d1 (master)
| Author: frigo <frigo@dev>
| Date:   Fri Nov 7 20:24:18 2014 +0100
|     Fifth
| * commit bf3b476491547523321c765857de2097f77cdbd5 (branch1)
|/  Author: frigo <frigo@dev>
|   Date:   Fri Nov 7 20:23:54 2014 +0100
|       branch1 first
* commit 13f93d5ca898a043d37d704d397d34cf1f133a05
| Author: frigo <frigo@dev>
| Date:   Fri Nov 7 20:20:12 2014 +0100
|     Fourth
* commit 94f2fa1bb654288860c6af34c0cc9ff1267e0e72
| Author: frigo <frigo@dev>
| Date:   Fri Nov 7 20:19:57 2014 +0100
|     Third
* commit 5333eb26b57b038b3b4fdf2cb91590c0254b4024
| Author: frigo <frigo@dev>
| Date:   Fri Nov 7 20:19:24 2014 +0100
|     Second
* commit be69a7194413d9760b9f8930edf79afe7095b716
  Author: frigo <frigo@dev>
  Date:   Fri Nov 7 20:18:55 2014 +0100

      First
```

As I expected, the following shows no difference:

```
git diff 13f93d5 a6a091c
```

But still all the commit after the rebased commit remain attached to the old commit hierarchy.

I also tried creating a grafts file with no parent for `13f93d5`and running `git filter-branch` to "carve it into stone", but that still leaves me with the history visible with `git --all`.

Answer (score 1):

git checkout aSHA1 means you are in a detached HEAD mode.

You should make your interactive rebase with:

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i --root
```

Do the reword and fixup you did, while picking d9da0f2 (the current master HEAd)

Note that will leave `branch1` stranded:

```
# after the rebase:

git branch -f branch1 master~1
git checkout branch1
git cherry-pick bf3b476
```

Comment: Thank you! Good answer. My problem is that the real repository I try to change has two years worth of history I am trying to get rid of and ca. 15-20 feature branches. Cherry picking all the commits for all the branches is not for the faint hearted(=me). I guess my question was not the best.

Comment: @frigo you can cherry-pick a range of commits though (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309: it still would work just fine.